# Display all phone numbers assigned to a contact?

Tags: android, contacts, phone-number

Here is my code which give me the contact's name and phone number by click on list item:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    final String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DISPLAY_NAME"));
    Cursor contCursor =(Cursor) listStarred.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String strid = contCursor.getString(contCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    String name = null;
    String lname ="...";

    contCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +"='"+strid+"'",
            null, null);

    int phoneNumberIndex = contCursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    Log.d("Count", String.valueOf(contCursor.getCount()));

    if (contCursor != null) {
        Log.v("CurNotNull", "Cursor Not null");
        try {
            if (contCursor.moveToNext()) {
                Log.v("MoveToFirst", "Moved to first");
                Log.v("CheckMTF", "Cursor Moved to first and checking");
                lname = contCursor.getString(phoneNumberIndex);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contactName + " " + lname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } finally {
            Log.v("Finally", "In finally");
            contCursor.close();
        }
}
}
```

The above code seems that works fine, but how can instead of get one phone number to get a list with all contact's numbers?
What changes need to be done to get an array with the numbers(and type of each) for the selected contact?

Answer (score 0):

The user which answered deleted his answer, but he actually help me with the code he/she provided.
I was able to get the other numbers using a part of the code provided. So here is the improved code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    final String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DISPLAY_NAME"));
    contCursor =(Cursor) listStarred.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String strid = contCursor.getString(contCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    ArrayList<String> phones = new ArrayList<String>();
    contCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +"='"+strid+"'",
            null, null);

    while (contCursor.moveToNext()){
        String phoneNo = contCursor.getString(contCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Now just need to save the numbers on an array or list to populate a listview.